# Почему нельзя использовать NEWID() в функциях?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Собственно вопрос, почему его нельзя использовать в функциях и группу других похож недетерминированных функций(Например, Rand())?

Это какая-то особенность MS SQL или и в других СУБД похожая ситуация?

Со стороны я не вижу причин запрета.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Способ обхода:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/775573/5741205)

```
create view getNewID as select newid() as new_id

create function myfunction ()
returns uniqueidentifier
as begin
   return (select new_id from getNewID)
end
```

Почему - [возможно NEWID() изменяет состояние БД:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine)

- User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.

Comment: А newid() как-то изменяет состояние БД?

Comment: @iluxa1810, возможно (я видел ответы в английской SO, где утверждали что изменяет), точно сказать не могу

Comment: А Rand? Неужели он тоже что-то меняет? Просто, не верится...

Comment: @iluxa1810, посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531517/5741205)

Comment: А в других СУБД такая же ситуация?